# How to test JavaScript code with Chutzpah in Visual Studio 2015 and ASP.NET 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jasmine, visual-studio-2015, chutzpah

I'm writing a web application in ASP.NET 5 (Mvc 6) so I do use the new JSon files to manage packages.

Now I have a web application which contains all my controllers and a couple of self-written JavaScript files that are required to render the UI.

So, I've created a `package.json` file that contains dependencies that my JavaScript needs. Here's a snippet of it:

```
{
  "name": "kando.cms",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "gulp": "3.9.0",
    "gulp-sass": "2.1.1"
  }
}
```

Then I've created a new test library project, in which I do reference my ASP.NET application through the project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Kando.Cms.Test Class Library",
  "authors": [ "kdc" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "Kando.Cms": "1.0.0-*" 
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": { }
  }
}
```

I've also created a package.json to install jQuery and Jasmine:

```
{
  "name": "kando.cms.test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This package is used to test the JavaScript functions that can be found in 'Kando.Cms' project.",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "jasmine": "2.4.1"
  }
}
```

As the last thing, I've installed Chutzpah Visual Studio extension to have my unit tests show up in the Test Explorer.

Here's a very basic test, that doesn't test anything in the Kando.cms project:

```
describe("My Simple JavaScript Unit Test", function() {
    it("Add 2 numbers", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

That's all working fine, but how can I reference my JavaScript function in the other project so I can test that.

Also, how to I enable Visual Studio Intellisense for Jasmine?
See the screenshot below, everything is underlined in Visual Studio, however it's all working:

[image]

**Edit: Jasmine Intellisense:**

Okay, the Jasmine Intellisense is working right now.
I've added a reference to the file containing the tests:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js" />
```

Only one thing more right now and that's how to reference private packages stored in another project in the same solution.

Comment: This is something I am also trying to figure out. I'm also implementing a "modular" asp.net 5 system.